# Reflection to Get `Parent` Object

Tags: c#, reflection

I'm pretty sure this isn't possible, but thought I'd ask anyways.

Say I have:

```
public class A
{
    public B BInstance { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public Type GetParentType()
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

Is there any possible way, via reflection, for `B`'s `GetParentType` to return `typeof(A)` at runtime?

I know I could simply pass `typeof(this)` into `B` when I initialize it on `A`, I'm just curious.

Comment: OK So I think you could do this but it'd be a terribly inefficient way to do get that relationship.  You could get all the classes inside of your namespace, then you could check each class you found to see if it has a type of B.  This would be how you could find A, but there is no direct link between A and B that I can see.

Comment: _If_ you need to know this, it's almost always a design smell. You cannot do it anyway. Can you explain why you need this instead?

Comment: @CodeCaster I could certainly see how it appears to be a design smell.  We're starting work on a framework consisting of composable modules that you can drop onto classes that encapsulate distinct responsibilities.

Comment: Sounds like you could just give your classes a `Container` property that gives it a reference to its parent. :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The answer is no, as far i know, because when you write that

```
var t = new B () ;
```

the new B instance has no information on where will be stored, so as that istance has no cognition on the fact that is stored in a var, the ones in your example do not know is put in a property of an A instance.

Answer (score 1):

Please don't actually do this...

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Threading;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var xx = B.GetParentType();
    }
}

public class A
{
    public B b { get; set; }
}

public class B
{
    public static List<Type> GetParentType()
    {
        var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
                where t.IsClass && t.GetProperties().Any(p => p.PropertyType == typeof(B))
                select t;
        return q.ToList();
    }
}
```

Comment: well yeah, but I need the specific one.  `B` is validation logic that you can drop on a class that needs validation, in theory.

Comment: Then I'm fairly sure that the answer is no, but if someone can I'll be impressed.

Answer (score 1):

The code is messy, but it works :

```
public class A { public B BInstance { get; set; } }

public class Z { public B BInstance { get; set; } }

public class C { public Z BInstance { get; set; } }

public class B
{
    public List<Type> GetParentTypes()
    {
        Type thisType = this.GetType();
        FieldInfo f = null;
        PropertyInfo p = null;
        Assembly assembly = Assembly.GetAssembly(thisType);

        List<Type> types = 
            assembly.DefinedTypes
            .Where(t => t.IsClass
                && t.GetMembers().Any(m =>
            {
                if ((f = m as FieldInfo) != null)
                    return f.FieldType == thisType;
                return (p = m as PropertyInfo) != null &&
                                 p.PropertyType == thisType;
            }))
            .Select(t => t.AsType())
            .ToList();

        return types;
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        B instance = new B();
        List<Type> types = instance.GetParentTypes();

        foreach (var type in types)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Output :

A Z