# How can I get a variables "full path"?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

So say I have the classes. I want to be able to get a variables full path based on the class hierarchy

```
class A {
   string a {get; set;}
}

class B {
   A a {get; set;}
}

class C {
   B b {get; set}
}

class Main {
   static void main(string[] args){
      C c = new C();
      var path = GetPath(c=>c.b.a);          
   }

   static string GetPath<T>(Expression<Func<T>> prop){
      //So if I have a method which prints the strings full path
      //I want to retrieve as a string "C.B.a"
      //How could I get this path
   }
}
```

Comment: Isn't that what you sent to the method? c.b.a?

Comment: If you can clarify why you want to achieve than someone can help... Obviously there is no way to do it exactly as you are asking - `getPath(42)` ??? (You may want to look into expression trees similar how Moq uses them)

Comment: @AAA i want it to be uppercase (The class name)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov ok I have edited the getPath parameter

Comment: You probably can't do it that way, as you are passing in a string the way you have it.  You can probably get it if you pass in a lamda instead... `getPath(c=>c.b.a)`, maybe.

Comment: @RobertMcKee yes I forgot to update this

Comment: Why would you call a method to give you the path as `getPath(c.b.a)` if you already have it? You know it's `c.b.a` at compile time.

Comment: " (The class name)" it looks for me more like you want the names of the variables as a string. why exactly would you need it?

Comment: @CodingYoshi i want to get that path...it could be any prop passed...this is just one example

Comment: So... [TypeOf().BaseType()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.type.basetype?view=netframework-4.8) . Looks like duplicated of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34424787/reflection-to-get-parent-object

Comment: I get that but my question is why bother calling a method? You have it and you know it at compile time.

Comment: Exactly my first comment! Give a valid example for what you are doing

Comment: this will be a static method which i can pass any property to...i don' t know all my props before runtime @CodingYoshi

Comment: Try `HtmlHelper.NameFor(c=>c.b.a)`

Comment: @YusufJama, can you edit your post to give such an example? Also look at [GetType](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.object.gettype?view=netframework-4.8) and [TypeOf](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/type-testing-and-conversion-operators#typeof-operator)

Comment: "i don' t know all my props before runtime", give me an example please. How is it possible you don't know then what would you pass to the method?

Comment: @CodingYoshi A serializer, an ORM, something that takes an object based on interface, or anything that uses DI -- you would have an object with properties you don't know ahead of time, or at least your library doesn't have ahead of time.

Comment: @robertmckee Yes but that's very different than what the OP is asking. The OP knows the path but wants to call a method with the path to get the path. I guess the question is not clear so hard to tell.

Comment: @CodingYoshi i want to return a string based on what i passed....i cannot simply return "C.B.a" but i think Robert McKee answered what I needed...something similar to NameFor

Comment: But why are you passing it in? You know it so why pass it.

Comment: this is simply an example...this method could be called 1049348 times and returns based on whatever is passed....if I created a variable of type B and passed this into the function GetPath(b=>b.a), i would want "B.a" to return

Comment: Your expected output seems to be using the class types for the first few accesses, but the property name for the final one. Question: If the `C` type had two properties of type `B`, named `b1` and `b2`, would you want `GetPath(() => c.b1.a)` and `GetPath(() => c.b2.a)` to both return `"C.B.a"`?

Comment: @yusufjama I don't think you follow what I am trying to say. If you call `GetPat(b=>b.a)`, it will return `B.a`. My point is why even call `GetPath`, you know it is `B.a` so skip calling another method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel like I should let you know that I'm hardly an expert with `Expression`, so there is a good possibility that if you try to throw something at this that is more complex than your example it won't work. For example, if you were to try to do something like: `C.b.GetAnA().a` it wouldn't work. But, it might give you a starting point to figure the rest out on your own.

```csharp
static string GetPath<T>(Expression<Func<T>> prop)
{
    var body = prop.Body as System.Linq.Expressions.MemberExpression;
    if (body is null)
    {
        return null;
    }
    string res = body.Member.Name;
    MemberExpression expr = body;
    while ((expr = (expr.Expression as MemberExpression)) != null)
    {
        if (expr.Member is FieldInfo fi)
        {
            res = fi.FieldType.Name + "." + res;
        }
        else if (expr.Member is PropertyInfo pi)
        {
            res = pi.PropertyType.Name + "." + res;
        }
    }
    return res; 
}
```